# Resize returns "Unsupported image format." on Magento

Tags: php, magento

I need to resize a image that come from media folder, but when i use the following code magento returns this erros.

> "Unsupported image format."

Code:

```
<?php $fileName = $post->getImagemdestacada(); ?>
<?php

$folderURL = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
$imageURL = $folderURL . $fileName;

$basePath = Mage::getBaseDir(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . DS . $fileName;
$newPath = Mage::getBaseDir(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . DS . "blog" . DS . $fileName;

$image= new Varien_Image($basePath);
$image->resize(200, 200);
$image->save($imageResized);

?>
```

I've already tried to use timthumb on magento, but didn't work too, aparently the magento denied my access to this folder using php.